# Get data from Form 2 To Form1 And close

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class

Account.cs

```
namespace EasyFtp
{
    class Account
    {
        public String Username;
        public String Password;
        public String FtpServer;
    }
}
```

and i have MainWindow Form (Main window for my application ) and logForm with 3 textbox and button. I want to log to my ftp server before show my mainwindow , so i have to showdialog my logform and when thus user press button it get all information from logform and pass it to my mainwindow and save data in object of Account class ; my question is how i pass the data.

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace EasyFtp
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Form
    {
        private Account myaccount; 
        LogInForm g; 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = new LogInForm();
            g.ShowDialog();



        }

        /* how i continue the code */
    }
}
```

LogInForm

```
namespace EasyFtp
{

    public partial class LogInForm : Form
    {       

        public LogInForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*log in code (not created yet)*/
            this.Dispose();
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Your Main window

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = "original text";
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Your dialog-form, that will change the values in Form1

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Get the text from Form1
    textBoxOrg.Text = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["textBox1"].Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change the text on Form1
    Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["textBox1"].Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

You probably wan't to change value on public properties instead of UI-elements.

Another, and cleaner way, is to pass fields to the form with a [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: thnx , but i want to show logform and the user pass ftp server and username and press ok , then i want main window save ftp server and username in an account and close logform